# How to stop the line graph at a certain point when the data stalls

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have cumulative sum of ticketed sales data by every month that is plotted for every day.
X axis is number of days (day 200, day 201). I have plotted a measure which does the cumulative sum

```
  CALCULATE (
  SUM ( 'Sales'[Apr-2023] ),
  FILTER ( All('Sales'),
  'Sales'[Days To Event] >= Max('Sales'[Days To Event]
  )
  ))
```

I would like the data for months where the ticketed sales stalls to stop the line. Is there a way to use If statement combined with this measure? Or add a filter on the page like a flag to say if the sales data = sales data as previous day it should stop?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say if there are no sales on that date then stop. Try something like:

```
my measure = 
  var result =
    CALCULATE (
      SUM ( 'Sales'[Apr-2023] ),
      FILTER (
        All('Sales'),
       'Sales'[Days To Event] >= MAX('Sales'[Days To Event])
      )
    )
  return
    IF( SUM( 'Sales'[Apr-2023] ) > 0, result)
```